# How to convert perl hash of hash of hash to php

Tags: php, perl, hash

I am currently looking a rewriting some perl cgi scripts into php, mainly in order so I can learn php. Everything is going well, except I can't get my head round how to convert a perl hash of hash of hash into a php array.
Take this scenario (not real, but the idea is the same)
I have 5 network nodes called A,B,C,D,E.
Each node is actually a stack of 3 switches called TOP, MIDDLE, BOTTOM
Each switch has 10 interfaces called 1 to 10.

I have a script that polls round every interface and record the input bytes in a database like this:-

```
node   switch   interface  bytes
 A      TOP       1         999
 B     MIDDLE     1         999
 A     MIDDLE     2         999
```

etc

I can read the database in php, but then I come unstuck. In perl I just read the data and store it in a hash of hashes by looping though the query of the database

```
`While $ref fetchrow_hashref() {
    $hash{$ref{'NODE'}}{$ref{'Switch'}}{$ref{'Interface'}=$ref{'Bytes'}
}`
```

So now I can access any value in my cgi code using the names
`$hash{A}{Top}{1}` would return 999

But when I try and do something similar in php with associative array of arrays, it go wrong. I've used

```
$hash[]=[$ref["NODE"}=>
    [$ref["Switch"]=>
        [$ref["Interface"]=>
            $ref["Bytes"]
        ]
    ]
];
```

A var_dump of the hash looks correct, but I don't appear to be able to print a value out of the array using
`print $hash[A][TOP][1];`

Please can I have pointers to my mistakes

Comment: What is that `$ref` array in the PHP code? If you set the value of `$hash['A']['TOP'][1]`, you get it back in the same way. References are automatically dereferenced in PHP, so for example iterating over an array or an array of references will be just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
while( $ref=somefetchingfunction_or_method() ) {
    $hash[$ref['NODE']][$ref['Switch']][$ref['Interface']]=$ref['Bytes'];
```

(i.e. just replacing all `{` by `[`, `}` by `]` and fixing the missing last `]`.)

edit: [sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
$hash = [];
foreach( gen_fetch() as $ref ) {
    $hash[$ref['NODE']][$ref['Switch']][$ref['Interface']]=$ref['Bytes'];
}
echo $hash['A']['TOP'][1];

// generator requires php version >= 5.5, see http://php.net/language.generators.overview
function gen_fetch() {
    $keys = ['NODE','Switch','Interface','Bytes'];
    foreach( [['A','TOP',1,997],['B','MIDDLE',1,998],['A','MIDDLE',2,999]] as $r) {
        yield array_combine($keys,$r);
    }
}
```

prints `997`.

Comment: Thanks for the input that got it working. Sorry for the typos in the original post.